# Open specific page of an App developed in Appcelerator Titanium using PushWoosh

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, pushwoosh

We are developing an app in Appcelerator Titanium and using PushWoosh to send notifications. We have tried with no success to send a notification that opens an specific page in the app.

Think of an Inbox, where the user gets its messages, when a message is received, a notification shows up notifying the user on the new message, the user clicks it and opens the app on either the inbox or the message itself. The app includes other pages/features besides the Inbox, so far we can open the app after clicking but not the inbox or the message page.

We have looked everywhere for information and we would appreciate it if you can point us to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the page you want to open as a JSON string in the additional data tab, as explained here:

"Custom data: you can pass any additional JSON data in a {“key”:”value”} format, which you may use for deep linking."

https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/advanced-form-tutorial/

When the app is opened you can check the data attribute and open the page you want.

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen! we did all that, the problem is actually reading the information. I can't seem to find how to get {"key":"value"} from the custom data in Titanium. Any clue?

Comment: Did you take a look at this page:
https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/appcelerator-titanium-integration/.
It seems you have to define a callback function in the register part, this callback recieves all the data in the first attribute:  function receivePush(e) {
        alert('Received push: ' + JSON.stringify(e));

Your custom data should be in the 'e'

Answer (score 0):

Building on Jereon's response, in addition to passing additional data in the push notification - how are you acting upon the push notification? It seems the logical place to define UI actions on push notifications is in the callback defined when the device/app registers to receive push notifications.  This action will vary based on how you manage your UI/views.